# Three.JS Lines with different materials and directional light intensity

Tags: javascript, three.js

Three.js is very good, but I have a little problem.

I created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ntsim/aekPu/4/

```
var railingGeo = new THREE.Geometry();
    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(50, 25, 50));
    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(50, 35, 50));

    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-50, 35, 50));
    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-50, 25, 50));
    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-50, 35, 50));

    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-50, 35, -50));
    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-50, 25, -50));
    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(-50, 35, -50));

    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(50, 35, -50));
    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(50, 25, -50));
    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(50, 35, -50));

    railingGeo.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(50, 35, 50));

    var yellowLineBasicMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: 0x777700,
        shading: THREE.FlatShading
    });

    var yellowMeshPhongMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ //shininess: 40,
        specular: 0x770000,
        ambient: 0x770000,
        emissive: 0x000000,
        color: 0x777700,
        shading: THREE.FlatShading
    });

    var railing=new THREE.Line(railingGeo,yellowLineBasicMaterial); // railing glows yellow when lights are out
    //var railing = new THREE.Line(railingGeo, yellowMeshPhongMaterial); // railing dims when lights goo out but WEBGL ERROR ocurs 
    // error is:WebGL: INVALID_OPERATION: vertexAttribPointer: no bound ARRAY_BUFFER 

    building.add(railing);
    return building;
```

In this scene I created a little building with a railing on the roof with one directional light.
The intensity of the light oscillates over time between 0 and 100.

My question is about the railing, which is really just a set of simple lines.

I want the entire building and the railing to go dark as the intensity of the light goes to zero.

Check lines 72 and 73 of my fiddle.

When my railing is created with a LineBasicMaterial, the railing always glows, regardless of light intensity. That's not what I want.

If I change my material properties of the railing to a MeshPhongMaterial, then the 
railing does somewhat fade to dark as the light intensity goes to zero, BUT this code produces a "WEBGL ERROR: INVALID_OPERATION: vertexAttribPointer: no bound ARRAY_BUFFER" on the Chrome browser console.

I think I understand why the WEBGL error. I think its because lines don't have normals to reflect the light back? or something like that.

Never the less, it seems to me that I should be able to force some sort of material property with my lines, so that the line color intensity can somehow be reduced by the overall light intensity of the scene, without getting a WEBGL error. A number of years ago I wrote a c++ program using opengl and I was able to do this without any issues. Could this possible be a THREE.js bug or a WEBGL problem?  I could dynamically change the color values of my lines when the light intensity changes, but is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`LineBasicMaterial` does not respond to lights, and the other materials are not appropriate for lines for the reasons you mentioned.

You could do something like this:

```
yellowLineBasicMaterial.color.setRGB( light.intensity / 100, light.intensity / 100, 0 );
```

Another solution is to use `CubeGeometry` for the railing, `MeshPhongMaterial` for the railing material, and set `wireframe: true`. In that case, you should get the effect you want.

three.js r.58